# Vertical swipe event using kendo ui

Tags: jquery, mobile, kendo-ui, swipe

How can I detect vertical swipe event using kendo ui for mobile? It seems that only horizontal swipe is supported in JQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently Kendo UI supports only horizontal swipes.